# como puedo ordenar estos diccionarios en la lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

¿Cómo puedo ordenar estos diccionarios según la suma de la cantidad de productos vendidos? Por ejemplo, el id 1, en total, vendió 80 productos. Pero, ¿cómo puedo llegar a ese resultado?

```
productos[
{"id": 1 , "precio":2000 , "año":2019 , "vendidos":30},
{"id": 2 , "precio":2000 , "año":2019 , "vendidos":15},
{"id": 3 , "precio":2000 , "año":2019 , "vendidos":20},
{"id": 1 , "precio":2000 , "año":2020 , "vendidos":50},
{"id": 2 , "precio":2000 , "año":2021 , "vendidos":100}
]
```

Comment: Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el código que lograste hasta ahora por favor (aunque no funcione)? [Con formato](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). De este modo tu pregunta evitará parecerse a una del tipo "este es mi ejercicio, resuelvanlo"

Answer (score 1):

El programa toma un diccionario e inserta los id (no repetidos, es decir en este caso 1,2 y 3) en un array llamado lista_id. Tras esto hago otro bucle que los vaya recorriendo dichos id. Llamando a la función suma(y): En esta función se hace otro bucle que si recorra todos los id del diccionario y vaya comparando, si los id son iguales y el numero de ventas es distinto entonces va a sumar las ventas de esos dos id iguales. Si no, entonces la suma va a ser simplemente las ventas que ya tenia ese id.

```
productos = [{"id": 1, "precio": 2000, "año": 2019, "vendidos": 30},
             {"id": 2, "precio": 2000, "año": 2019, "vendidos": 15},
             {"id": 3, "precio": 2000, "año": 2019, "vendidos": 20},
             {"id": 1, "precio": 2000, "año": 2020, "vendidos": 50},
             {"id": 2, "precio": 2000, "año": 2021, "vendidos": 100}]


def suma(y):
    suma = productos[y]['vendidos']
    for i in range(0, len(productos)):
        if productos[y]['id'] == productos[i]['id'] and productos[y]['vendidos'] != productos[i]['vendidos']:
            suma = productos[y]['vendidos'] + productos[i]['vendidos']
    return suma


lista_id = []

for i in range(0, len(productos)):
    if productos[i]['id'] not in lista_id:
        lista_id.append(productos[i]['id'])

for i in range(0, len(lista_id)):
    print("El id: " + str(lista_id[i]) + " en total vendio: " + str(suma(i)))
```

Comment: y que hace esto? Por favor lee [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Usa la función sorted presente en los built-in de Python, intenta esto

```
ordenados = sorted(productos,key=lambda x:x['vendidos'])
```

La función sorted recibe como parámetros la lista que deseas ordenar y el parámetro key es una función que le indica a sorted como debe ordenar, en este caso `lambda x: x['vendidos']` le dice a sorted que como todos los elementos de la lista son diccionarios escoja para comparar la llave vendidos de cada diccionario. Quizás es extraño ver lambda en el código pero es una abreviatura para funciones, si tienes dudas consulta la documentación.

Comment: nop, eso no servirá, pues cada sub-diccionario tiene un `id` y el quiere que se ordene según el total de vendidos, es decir agrupar todos los mismos `id` y luego ordenar

Answer (score 0):

Soy nuevo en programación y mi lógica no es excelente, por lo tanto, no sé si se puede acortar, esto es lo que llevo, pero me dio sueño, entonces traten de arreglarlo, después edito la respuesta si consigo algo mejor

```
# creo el diccionario
productos = [
    {"id": 1, "precio": 2000, "año": 2019, "vendidos": 30},
    {"id": 2, "precio": 2000, "año": 2019, "vendidos": 15},
    {"id": 3, "precio": 2000, "año": 2019, "vendidos": 20},
    {"id": 1, "precio": 2000, "año": 2020, "vendidos": 50},
    {"id": 2, "precio": 2000, "año": 2021, "vendidos": 100}
]

def ordenar(diccionario):
    id_maximo = 0
    ids = []
    vendidos = []
    sumado = []
    resultado = []
    for x in diccionario:
        if id_maximo < x["id"]:
            id_maximo = x["id"]

    for x in range(id_maximo):
        ids.append(x + 1)

    for z in ids:
        total = 0
        for x in diccionario:
            if z == x["id"]:
                total = total + x["vendidos"]
        vendidos.append(total)

    vueltas = 0
    while True:
        sumado.append({"id": ids[vueltas], "total": vendidos[vueltas]})
        if vueltas + 1 == id_maximo:
            break
        vueltas = vueltas + 1

    maximo = 0
    vueltas = 0
    idd = None
    index = 0
    while True:
        if not len(sumado) - 1 == 0 and vueltas <= len(sumado) - 1:
            z = sumado[vueltas]
        if z["total"] > maximo:
            idd = z["id"]
            maximo = z["total"]
            index = vueltas

        if vueltas == len(sumado) - 1:
            resultado.append({"id": idd, "total vendidos": maximo})
            sumado.pop(index)
            maximo = 0
            vueltas = 0
            index = 0
            continue

        if len(sumado) == 0:
            break
        vueltas = vueltas + 1

    print(resultado)

ordenar(productos)
```

Comment: yy.... que hace esto?

Comment: Los datos se unen y se ordenan desendente

Comment: es mas efectivo con una base de datos o algo asi pero nose si te sirva

Comment: no me refería a eso, en realidad entiendo todo el código y sé perfectamente que haces pero no todos lo entenderán, por eso es necesario añadir una explicación en tu respuesta. La respuesta es para todos no solo para ti o para el autor de la pregunta, sino **todos**. Por favor lee [answer]

Comment: a bueno, una gran disculpa , ya le coloco comentarios

Comment: No te preocupes, entiendo que eres nuevo, pero siempre se debe seguir las reglas. Por cierto si quieres saber como reducir tu código puedes ver el mio [aquí](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1B57W-uIIQ2L3SOKyWWRynHVHPD2HRuK-?usp=sharing), la verdad quería dejar que otros respondan la pregunta pero ninguna ha logrado responder bien :c.

Comment: Pero porque no usas una base de datos como SQLite que te resultaría

Comment: Ya lograste lo que querías según lo que pasaste

Comment: jaja, yo no soy el que hizo la pregunta :/